# Replace reference in formula with precedent

Tags: vba, excel, reference

I have an excel file with three sheets (1,2,3), in the first sheet are primary data, in the third sheet are final data for output and the second sheet is bridge between them. I need to update formulas in the third sheet so I can delete the second sheet.

For example, there is value in sheet "1" in cell A1, then in sheet "2" is C5='1'!A1, in sheet "3" B4='2'!C5, and I need to get in sheet "3" B4='1'!A1. I need to do this for thousands of cells, therefore it is impossible to do it manually and I was thinking about using macro, but I was unable to create such macro. Can somebody help me?

This question raised because the bridge in sheet "2" is complex and not only assign one value from sheet "1" to one cell but it also add up several cells from sheet "1" together, therefore there is not any simple way to replace the bridge by `vlookup` or similar function.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty difficult to answer this question the way you have written it. This is because it seems all the cells in Sheet3 point to a "random" spot in sheet 2. If there is no rhyme or reason to how sheet pulls its numbers, replacing the formulas could be hard. However, try this:

If sheet 3 cells only EVER refers to a single cell in sheet 2, and sheet to only EVER refers to sheet 1, then you can go to sheet 2, and press CTRL + H. This will bring up the "find and replace" function. Replace all instances of "=" with "ZZZZ=". When you look to sheet3, you will see that instead of giving the values calculated off of sheet1 through sheet 2, a cell in sheet3 could say something like "ZZZZ='sheet1'!A1+'sheet1'!B1", because that's the value of sheet 2 that it points at. From there, copy and paste all of sheet3 to values only. Then, CTRL + H again and replace all instances in sheet of "ZZZZ=" with "=".

However I doubt this will work as if sheet2 contains values used elsewhere in sheet2 to calculate, or if sheet3 refers to things in other ways, this will fall apart.

Comment: As you have written, there is problem with this solution in the case where in the sheet 3 cell refers to more than a single cell in sheet 2. But if the cell refers only to one cell it works. So if there wont be better solution I think with some manual work I can use this.

Comment: @lulish89 If you found this answer helpful please mark as 'answered'.